# Error occured when updating system

Tags: command-line, apt, updates, software-center, update-manager

I have a problem during updating my Ubuntu system using terminal.

Recently, there was two warning message appears on my terminal which like below:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu/dists/trusty-getdeb/apps/binary-i386/Packages  521  Origin Down [IP: 141.101.116.236 80]
```

and

```
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu/dists/trusty-getdeb/games/binary-i386/Packages  521  Origin Down [IP: 141.101.116.236 80]
```

I don't know how could this happen. I thought, maybe it was from my Wi-fi connection but it's not. And I've tried to update again my system using my terminal and that problem is still appear. So, I hope if you guys can tell me what and why the warning messages appear.

And I hope will get solution from anyone.

Comment: Try changing the server  from Softwares & Updates > Ubuntu tab.

Comment: I have change the server to the main server and I have update it again and the warnings are still appear. And I've alert there is an another alert after the two warnings show as below:

E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

Comment: What I can interpret from the error is that the mentioned server is currently down. So, please try after sometime and see whether the problem persists. Thank You!

Comment: ooo.. but I have already disabled

http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu/dists/trusty-getdeb/apps/binary-i386/Packages 

and 

http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu/dists/trusty-getdeb/games/binary-i386/Packages

at Software and Update apps, and the problem have been solved..

Comment: Glad it helped!

Answer (score 0):

Yes good idea to disable, but if you have installed any software from the GetDeb repository, it will not be updated anymore. So disabling this repository temporarily is a good idea while you wait for the Getdeb server to be online again, as explained by [Raphael](https://askubuntu.com/users/119531/raphael). You should try to enable it again after some time.